# Struggling to get data from POST request data from a HTML form with flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I've been working on a website back-end using the python library flask but whenever I try and get the form data from a POST request (as it needs to be sent securely) I always get a 405 - Method not allowed error. After the submission of a user's email and password at the moment its just meant to send them to a very basic html page with their name and email on it (it's easier to explain with the code).

python code:

```
# reroutes user to login page html file
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reroute_login():
    return flask.render_template("login.html")


# returns the login page html file
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        print("Reached")
        email = flask.request.form["email"]
        password = flask.request.form["password"]
        print(email, password)
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for("user", usr=email))
    else:
        return flask.render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return f"<h1>{usr}</h1>" # here is that very basic html page I mentioned but it won't reroute to this page
```

login.html:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <h1>Login</h1>
        
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <a href="#">Forgot Your Password</a>

    <input type="submit" class="button1" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Please just know I'm very new to Flask and back-end web dev as a whole but any kind of help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you are doing things the bad way, i suggest you reading the `Flask` official tutorial https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/, then go and read the Mega tutorial from Miguel Grinberg https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing action in login.html from `#` to `/login` .

And you have defined multiple routes with same name.
Remove the first route to login.